# Something going wrong with Button initialization

Tags: java, android

Whenever I try to run my app from a physical device it always crashes with a NullPointerException on the "setEnabled" line, or whatever method I'm trying to use.

Java:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView;
    ImageButton record;
    ImageButton stop;
    TextView textView2;
    TextView textView3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        record = findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        stop = findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
        textView2 = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        textView3 = findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        textView.setText("   Bienvenido a Bilder!");
        record.setEnabled(true);
```

XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/gris_claro"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    {...}

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="66dp"
        android:paddingRight="65dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/stop64"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.santper.bilder">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Your ImageButton's ID is `imageButton2`, but you're referencing `imageButton` in your code as well as `imageButton2`. Does `imageButton` exist in your XML?

Comment: Yes, I didn't post the whole XML on here but it's on the original file and it's the same as imageButton2 but with a different name and icon

Comment: And what's the name of that XML file you posted?

Comment: You need to post a [mcve]. If the error is with a missing element, it's clearly null, and results in the app crashing

Answer (score 0):

Is there a case that you're inflating the wrong xml file to `MainActivity` class?
In `onCreate()` there is this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
```

maybe you want:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a mismatch in java code and xml

JAVA
`record = findViewById(R.id.imageButton);`

XML
`android:id="@+id/imageButton2"`

It should be:
`record = findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);`

OR ther is no `android:id="@+id/imageButton"` in XML